# C# XmlDocument how to get pointer to root element and iterate over children

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In XML Document:

**Foo.xml**

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
          <name>Foo</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Bar</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

How to get this root element, iterate over his child elements and get their properties?

**Bar.cs**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path + "/foo.xml");

XmlNode mainNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("products");
XmlNode root = mainNode.FirstChild; //null

foreach (XmlNode node in mainNode)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(node["id"].InnerText);
    string name = node["name"].InnerText);
    list.Items.Add(id);
    list.Items.Add(name);
}
```

This code implicates that mainNode is null. What is the best practise of doing that?

Comment: This is the problem: `DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("products")` - the `DocumentElement` *is* the `products` element; there's no `products` element under it. As an aside, if you can possibly use `XDocument` (LINQ to XML) instead, that's a much cleaner API in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DocumentElement` is the outermost element of the XML, i.e. the `<products>` element. You can't select another `<products>` element below it.

What you can do:

```
XmlNode mainNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("products");
```

or

```
XmlNode mainNode = doc.DocumentElement;
```

or

```
XmlNode mainNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//products");
```

The second one is probably the fastest, since it does not need to parse and process a query. The last one is overkill and should be avoided for clean code reasons (KISS principle).